# Portable SQL with Group By and Joins

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables:

Table1:

```
Id DeviceName DeviceLocation AdditionalColumn1 AdditionalColumn2
1  xyz        Africa         SomeColText1      SomeText1
2  abc        USA            SomeColText2      SomeText2
```

Table2:

```
Id Name ExternalId DeviceName DeviceLocation Version
1  yyy  10          xyz        Africa         1 
2  bbb  11          xyz        Africa         1 
3  uuu  10          abc        USA            2
```

I'm trying to come up with an `SQ`L that would get me all the values out of `Table2` that joins with `Table1` and fetch me the additional fields from `Table1(AdditionalColumn1, AdditionalColumn2)`. Additionally, I want to get the elements from `Table2` that has the maximum `Version`. So the expected result should be:

```
Id Name ExternalId DeviceName DeviceLocation Version AdditionalColumn1 
2  bbb  11          xyz        Africa         1      SomeColText1
3  uuu  10          abc        USA            2      SomeColText2
```

I have a basic version setup, but what would be a much portable version that works across databases?

Comment: What is the connection between table1 and table2? What is version in Table2? It is version of what?

Comment: I could have multiple versions for a given externalId and that is tracked under the version column!

Comment: Table1 has a composite primary key which is the combination of DeviceName and DeviceLocation and I'm using this information in my Table2

Comment: Maybe your basic version is just what's needed!!

Comment: I still don't understand the criteria for picking id = `2` as opposed to id = `1`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be one of possible solutions:

```
select t2.Id,
       t2.Name, 
       t2.ExternalId,
       t2.DeviceName, 
       t2.DeviceLocation, 
       t2.Version, 
       t1.AdditionalColumn1,
       t1.AdditionalColumn2
from 
(select ExternalID, max(Version) as Version from Table2 group by ExternalID) tmp
join Table2 t2 on tmp.ExternalID = t2.ExternalID and tmp.Version = t2.Version
join Table1 t1 on t1.DeviceName = t2.DeviceName and t1.DeviceLocation = t2.DeviceLocation
```